# Does QSqlQuery release automatically?

Tags: c++, sqlite, qt5, qtsql

Does `QSqlQuery` release automatically? Qt Version:5.12 DataBase:SQLite

1. If a `QSqlquery` object goes out of scope, is it automatically released?
   Should I use `clear()` or `finish()` to release instead?
2. If I wanna use an `QSqlquery` many times, shoule I use `clear()` or `finish()` to release it?
   For example:

```cpp
QSqlQuery theQuery;
theQuery.exec("SELECT * From Table");
theQuery.next();

//some statements at the same scope

//Need to use clear() or finish() at there? (reuse)
theQuery.exec("SELECT * From Table2");
theQuery.next();
//Need to use clear() or finish() at there? (destruct)
return;
```

3. Should I use a global(long existence) `QSqlquery` object or a temporary one?

Comment: The answer is yes for #1 it is automatically released. And no for #2. You don't need to clear or finish in either question